# Алгоритм изменения цвета в зависимости от высоты C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

Есть набор точек, они отображаются средствами SharpDX. Необходимо что цвет точки менялся от красного к синему в зависимости от ее координаты Y, то есть от высоты. Я написал такой алгоритм:

```
 foreach (var contour in contours)
            {
                
                writer.WriteLine("///////////////");
                foreach (var point in contour.Points)
                {
                    if (point.Y == -10000 || point.Y == -100000) continue;
                    double normalizedY = (point.Y - (-0)) / (570 - (-0));
                    byte r = (byte)((1-normalizedY) * 255);
                    byte g = 0;
                    byte b = (byte)((normalizedY) * 255);
                   
                   var mainColor = new Color4(r, g, b, 255);
                    result.Add(new SharedTool.Contour.Point3D
                    {
                        X = point.X,
                        Y = point.Y,
                        Z = dZ,
                        Intensity = point.Intensity,
                        PointColor = mainColor
                    });
                }
             }
```

Для понимания оставляю ссылку на [файл с точками](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gHJWnRRZTEdbXyGIPeaO6pGSiFY_hj1b/view?usp=sharing).

Проблема в том, что как бы я не игрался с формулой, получается всегда что-то вроде этого[image]

То есть точки хаотично перемешиваются в своих цветах. Я пытаюсь добиться этого:
[image]

Comment: В SharpDX `Color4` принимает на вход `float` значения от 0 до 1.

Comment: Далее при использовании точек я нормализую их:
` colors.Add(new Color4(point.PointColor.Red / 255f, point.PointColor.Green / 255f, point.PointColor.Blue / 255f, point.PointColor.Alpha)); `

Comment: Вообще выглядит так что у вас в результате выставлено либо полностью Red либо полностью Blue, т.е. будто `normalizedY` или 1 или 0. Пройдитесь по коду дебаггером и всё должно стать понятно.

Comment: normalizedY меняется и находится в диапазоне от 0 до 1.  Встречаются 0.7, 0.4 и т.д

Comment: вот так выглядят цвета
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v9wnyQB0bOS8gKh5z00wicakQwjLJD7E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: не сильно вчитался в код (простите), но вам по сути нужно сначала перебрать все точки во всех контурах и найти min/max по высоте, а уже потом основываясь на этом высчитывать цвета. А иначе у вас диапазон высоты получается разный для разного набора точек, что в итоге приводит к тому что синие и красные точки идут в перемешку

Comment: Реализовал данный функционал, результат не поменялся

Comment: покажите новый код

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Yh5xIT5VlhLetApdCvmQ6WMS1o63xAs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `double normalizedY = point.Y / 570.0;` или если с min/max, то `= ((double)point.Y - min) / (max - min)`